# git reset --merge vs git reset --keep

Tags: git, git-reset

I have read
[the documentation](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html),
however I am having a hard time understanding the difference between

```
git reset --merge
```

And

```
git reset --keep
```

Please provide a simple explaination and/or example.

Comment: IMHO they're not exactly dupes. This one asks what they do, the other one asks why you would use them.

Comment: @SteveBennett They're close enough to be closed as dupes, IMO, but feel free to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are different when dealing with a merge conflict, for example this will generate a conflict

```sh
git init
echo 333 > foo.txt
git add foo.txt
git commit -m 333
git checkout -b feature
echo 444 > foo.txt
git commit -am 444
git checkout master
echo 555 > foo.txt
git commit -am 555
git merge feature
```

Then

```
$ git reset --keep
fatal: Cannot do a keep reset in the middle of a merge.

$ cat foo.txt
<<<<<<< HEAD
555
=======
444
>>>>>>> feature
```

Versus

```
$ git reset --merge

$ cat foo.txt
555
```

Answer (score 19):

I agree that the documentation is not very clear. From testing, I have found three differences, relating to what happens to files which:

- have staged changes
- no unstaged changes

In summary:

- `reset --merge` always discards the index (staged changes); aborts if unstaged and staged changes present on any file
- `reset --keep` keeps, but unstages, the index; aborts if the reset target touches the same file

Test scenario:

```
echo First > file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -m 'first'
git tag v1
echo Second >> file.txt
git commit -am 'second'
git tag v2
echo New > newfile.txt
git add newfile.txt
git commit -m 'third'
git tag v3
echo 'More stuff' >> file.txt
git add file.txt
```

We now have three commits, and 'file.txt' changes between v1 and v2, but does not change between commits v2 and v3.

#### No changes between index and new HEAD

In this situation:

- `git reset --merge v2` throws away those changes
- `git reset --keep v2` keeps them, but unstages them.

#### Changes between index and new HEAD

If we instead try to reset to v1:

- `git reset --merge v1` throws away the changes
- `git reset --keep v1` refuses:

  ```
  error: Entry 'file.txt' would be overwritten by merge. Cannot merge.
  fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'v1'.
  ```

#### Changes between index and new HEAD, plus unstaged changes

```
    git echo "Even more things" >> file.txt
```

Now, both fail, but with slightly different error messages:

- `git reset --merge v1`

  ```
  error: Entry 'file.txt' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
  fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'v1'.
  ```
- `git reset --keep v1`

  ```
  error: Entry 'file.txt' would be overwritten by merge. Cannot merge.
  fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'v1'.
  ```

#### Staged and unstaged changes to an unrelated file

```
echo Unrelated > unrelated.txt
git add unrelated.txt
echo Stuff >> unrelated.txt
```

Now this is somewhat odd:

- `git reset --merge v1`

  ```
  error: Entry 'unrelated.txt' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
  fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'v1'.
  ```
- `git reset --keep v1`

  Both sets of changes are kept, but unstaged.

#### No staged changes, but unstaged changes

For completeness, these both behave identically: the reset succeeds and the file remains unstaged.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, not only because it's thorough, but because the test scenario is copy-and-pasteable, so you can see for yourself.