# What are the differences between the --hard, --merge, and --keep for git reset?

Tags: git

The manpage of `git reset` says:

> --hard
>
> Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the
>   working tree since `<commit>` are discarded.
>
> --merge
>
> Resets the index and updates the files in the working tree that are
>   different between `<commit>` and `HEAD`, but keeps those which are
>   different between the index and working tree (i.e. which have changes
>   which have not been added). If a file that is different between 
>   `<commit>` and the index has unstaged changes, reset is aborted. In
>   other words,  --merge  does something like a
>   `git read-tree -u -m <commit>`,
>   but carries forward unmerged index entries.
>
> --keep
>
> Resets index entries and updates files in the working tree that are
>   different between `<commit>` and `HEAD`. If a file that is different
>   between `<commit>` and `HEAD` has local changes, reset is aborted.

I have trouble understanding the differences between the --hard, --merge, and --keep, possibly due to lack of understanding the different kinds of changes that are involved.

Could you rephrase and explain what they mean in more plain and explicit way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

--hard: This basically takes you to the commit that you have mentioned and any changes since that commit made in your local is deleted.

For difference between --keep and --merge see: [git reset --merge vs git reset --keep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728543/git-reset-merge-vs-git-reset-keep)